# Clustering machine learning algorithms

Tags: python, clustering, scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning

I am looking for a clustering algorithm that can separate my data into clusters. The data has three different variables and there are approx 500k samples. I need some control over the number of samples in each cluster - preferably the two clusters should be approximately equal in size.

Does this exist in a python package?

Comment: Why should the cluster sizes be equal? What if that is grossly inaccurate?

Comment: Because I need them to be, domain knowledge says it wont be.

Comment: Then what's wrong with something like k-means? If you "know" in some sense that the clusters will be about the same size, then k-means should reflect that.

Comment: What I meant was domain knowledge says it will not be grossly inaccurate even if I 'force' the sizes.